# jquery validator addmethod xregexp case insensitive

Tags: jquery, validation, xregexp

I'm trying to test a string using jquery.validator and xregexp but I need to be able to dynamically set a flag for case insensitivity.  Problem is I don't know how to send the flags for my xregexp to the addmethod using a param.  Here is what my addmethod currently looks like:

```
$.validator.addMethod(
    "regex",
    function(value, element, regexp) {
        var re = new XRegExp(regexp);
        return this.optional(element) || re.test(value);
    },
    "Please check your input."
);
```

And here is my call to it:

```
webAddr: {
    regex: '^(http(s)?:\/\/)?(([a-z]+[a-z0-9-\\.]*)\\.)+[a-z]{2,}$\\i',
    maxlength: 256,
    minlength: 4
},
```

My problem is the **\\i**.  I want to include it but according to the docs you have to include it as a separate param using this format:

```
XRegExp(regexp, flags);
```

How do I do I pass that dynamic using jquery.validator?

PS:  The reason I'm using xregexp and not something else is because I need true UTF-8 support elsewhere in my code, so I try to stick to using it for everything to help me get more proficient with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass an object for `regex` to separate the regex proper from the flags:

```
webAddr: {
    regex: {regex: '^(http(s)?:\/\/)?(([a-z]+[a-z0-9-\\.]*)\\.)+[a-z]{2,}$', 
            flags:'i'},
    maxlength: 256,
    minlength: 4
},
```

(I've changed the flag from `'\\i'` to `'i'` because I've never heard of `'\\i'` as a flag.)

And modify your validation code like this:

```
$.validator.addMethod(
    "regex",
    function(value, element, param) {
        var re = new XRegExp(param.regex, param.flags);
        return this.optional(element) || re.test(value);
    },
    "Please check your input."
);
```

I've not tested this code so watch out for typos.

Comment: ty ty Louis, that was the little bit of knowledge I was missing, it worked perfectly.  The **\\i** should have said **\/i** but in all my attempts to find a solution I forgot to swing it back in my example above.